# Link is not showing in webview

Tags: android, hyperlink

I want to show data and link of video in my web view but link is not showing.

Here is the java code-

```
String f_story_text = f_story_text.replaceAll("<b>", "");
            Spannable sp = new SpannableString(Html.fromHtml(f_story_text));
            Linkify.addLinks(sp, Linkify.ALL);
            final String html = "<body>" + Html.toHtml(sp) + "</body>";
            viewHolder.storyText.loadData(html, "text/html", "utf-8");
            viewHolder.storyText.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
```

Comment: what you exactly want in webview?

Comment: I want text and clickable link.when we click this link then its open into browser

Comment: If you want link to open in chrome or other browser then you don't need to set link in webview. If you want link to open in your app only then webview is needed

Comment: this is the my string                                                                             <div align="justify"><a href="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iHV_NmK7E1o"><font color="#ff0000"><i><b>पूरा गाना देखने के लिए यहां क्लिक करें।</b></i></font></a><br></div>

Comment: post your full .java code

Comment: but link is not showing only hindi words showing

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/104608/discussion-between-parsania-hardik-and-vijay-prakash).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your code as follow:

.xml:

```
 <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="youtube.com/watch?v=iHV_NmK7E1o"
        android:id="@+id/textview"/>
```

.java:

```
TextView tv;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

         tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textview);

    String tempString = "http://youtube.com/watch?v=iHV_NmK7E1o";
    SpannableString content = new SpannableString(tempString);
    content.setSpan(new UnderlineSpan(), 0, tempString.length(), 0);
    tv.setText(content);
    tv.setTextColor(Color.BLUE);
        tv.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                Intent browserIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("http://youtube.com/watch?v=iHV_NmK7E1o"));
                startActivity(browserIntent);
            }
        });
    }
```

you don't need webview just put your url in textview and click on it.It will open with browser you want